# Subquery django query to get biggest disctint values from objects and return those objects

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm, django-filter

So I have this query that I need to re-filter to get just the biggest taken_at field's value from distinct meter id, but I cannot get the django orm's/sql part to makes this query.

`<QuerySet [<Reading: [127] meter installation: 29, type: 1, taken: 2019-10-07 16:06:48.101453+00:00 value: 78.0000, comment: , VAT: 22.00>, <Reading: [126] meter installation: 41, type: 2, taken: 2019-10-07 14:05:32.415905+00:00 value: 7.0000, comment: asdfe, VAT: None>, <Reading: [125] meter installation: 41, type: 2, taken: 2019-10-07 14:02:37.588983+00:00 value: 7.0000, comment: asdfe, VAT: None>, <Reading: [124] meter installation: 49, type: 2, taken: 2019-10-07 12:19:49.067398+00:00 value: 8.0000, comment: , VAT: 2.00>`

this query contains lots of Reading objects, but I need to get just the biggest taken_at value from distinct meter installations, I've tried making annotation and then distinct , but they are not implemented together, I'm kinda new to SQL so any help would be great!

reading.py

```
class Reading(DateTrackedModel):
    meter_installation = models.ForeignKey(
        "MeterInstallation",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="readings",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_("Meter Installation"),
    )
    value = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0, verbose_name=_("Value")
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0, verbose_name=_("Price")
    )
    reading_type = models.ForeignKey(
        "MeterType",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="readings",
        verbose_name=_("Reading type"),
    )
    comment = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Comment"))
    taken_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=now, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Taken at"))
    VAT = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("VAT"))
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, unique=False, verbose_name=_("Unit name"))
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0.0, verbose_name=_("Unit price")
    )
```

MeterInstallation model:

```
class MeterInstallation(ActiveAfterUntilModel, DateTrackedModel, MPTTModel, NamedModel):  # type: ignore
    meter_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MeterType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="installations",
        verbose_name=_("Meter Installation type"),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", db_index=True
    )
    meter = models.ForeignKey(
        Meter, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="installations", null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Meter")
    )
    building = models.ForeignKey(
        Building,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="meter_installations",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_("Building"),
    )
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="meter_installations", blank=False, verbose_name=_("Places"))
    initial_reading = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0, verbose_name=_("Initial reading")
    )
    final_reading = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Final reading")
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what's the current status of your `Reading QuerySet`, but the general way of doing what you want can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values) in the docs. In your case it should be something like this:

```
reading_qs.values('meter_installation').annotate(max_taken_at=models.Max('taken_at'))
```

UPDATE:

So it wasn't very clear from the first post, but you are having the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. *(In your case n=1)*

One way to approach this specific version of the problem is via [window query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) *(if your database supports it)*. It should be something like this:

```
    reading_qs.annotate(max_taken_at=Window(
        expression=Max('taken_at'),
        partition_by=F('meter_installation')
    )).filter(max_taken_at=F('taken_at'))
```

**Update**: This actually won't work, because `Window` annotations are not filterable. I think in order to filter on window annotation you need to wrap it inside a `Subquery`, but with `Subquery` you are actually not obligated to use a `Window` function, there is another way to do it, which is my next example.

Another approach would be via [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) it will look like:

```
reading_qs.annotate(
    max_taken_at=Subquery(
            reading_qs.filter(meter_installation=OuterRef('meter_installation'))
            .values('meter_installation')
            .annotate(max_taken_at=Max('taken_at'))
            .values('max_taken_at')
    )
).filter(max_taken_at=F('taken_at'))
```

A third solution, which would be PostgreSQL only solution would be:

```
reading_qs.order_by(
    'meter_installation', '-taken_at'
).distinct('meter_installation')
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear in the title, I need to objects themselves not just values. This returns the needed values, but it returns just the `values` from objects from the queryset and then everything breaks in the app, since I need to get Reading objects themselves not just values from the queryset

Comment: So you want the `Reading` object with `taken_at` value equal to the greatest `taken_at` value from all `Reading` objects in the same `meter_installation` group is that correct ? (Its not very clear from the question)

Comment: Yes, I want to get just one Reading object with the biggest `taken_at` value from one meter_installation group as you might call that

Comment: Thank you so much for this help with these queries, I will also need to dig into these queries that you wrote and get a better sense of what is going here

Comment: Yes, its a big topic, maybe one nice introduction to the problem in plain SQL is [this one](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), take a look at it. You said you are new to SQL, you should really understand it in SQL first in order to understand how/what/why the ORM is doing.